# PHP custom CSV read, independent echos for different columns and rows

Tags: php, html, csv

I have a simple CSV with let's say 6 columns.

EDIT:
I can't find the mistake in the following, it's to do with selecting a key and using it as a variable I think:

```
$handle = fopen('hire_pa_amps.csv',"r");
while($values = fgetcsv($handle))
{
foreach('$values[0]' as $value0)
{
    echo($value0);
}
foreach('$values[1]' as $valuepound)
{
    echo('&pound'.$valuepound);
}
echo ('<br>'); }
fclose($handle); 



The data from the CSV file looks like this:
 "H/H ELECTRONICS VX200, 100 watts/channel stereo amplifier",70,30,20
  Electrovoice CP1800,84,36,24
```

In the meantime I've managed to do it somehow differently (and it works, for now) but I still want to know where the problem is in the code above (how to select a key in a array and manipulate it independently while using foreach). So the solution that I made for now:

```
$handle = fopen('hire_pa_amps.csv','r') or die("can't open file");

echo('<table class="pricesTable">');
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    list($column1, $column2, $column3, $column4) = $csv_line;

    echo('<tr>');

    echo    '<td>'.$column1.'</td>'.
            '<td>'.'&pound'.$column2.'</td>'.
            '<td>'.'&pound'.$column3.'</td>'.
            '<td>'.'&pound'.$column4.'</td>';
    echo('</tr>');
    }
fclose($handle) or die("can't close file");
echo('</table>');
```

Comment: That's not 3 questions, that's more like 3 demands. Have you had a good google and look about? There's plenty of CSV classes available to do what you're after.

Comment: Sorry if it looks that way, I'm not the person to ask in general. I did watched and read so many tutorials, but each one seem to have a different approach, and my situation is a bit unique. I'm sure it's simple for an advanced, but I'm a little stuck. I thought I could ask for once in my life :)

Comment: We don't mind questions but please do tell us what you've attempted and what you'd like to achieve. We get so many "it's broken, fix it for me" questions that we kinda... Prod the asker into showing what they've done to resolve

Comment: And just to clarify, I mean edit your question to include what tutorials you've tried and what issues you had with them- you're far more likely to get a response from people if they think you've done some of the hard work first.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php that'll parse a CSV string into an array. From there you should be able to pick out the stuff you want

Comment: Can we see a sample bit of input data too please?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your CSV to include column headers and then edit the column selection in the code below then this will work:

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
    return FALSE;

$header = NULL;
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
        else
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
return $data;
}

$csvArray = csv_to_array('hire_pa_amps.csv');
echo "<table>
<tr>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Markup</th>
    <th>VAT</th>
</tr>
";
foreach($csvArray as $currentProduct){
    echo "  <tr>
    <td>" . $currentProduct['Product Name'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $currentProduct['Price'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $currentProduct['Markup'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $currentProduct['VAT'] . "</td>
</tr>
";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I don't think you were thinking about the way the CSV was parsed to an array properly with your `foreach()`'s, you were trying to loop on $values[0] when you should have been looping on $values.